# How to default to immutable Seq in scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, sequence, immutability, seq

I learned today that scala's `Seq` can mean that both a mutable or immutable Seq can fulfill its type alias. (I stumbled over a [blogpost](https://orrsella.com/2014/02/27/the-default-scala-seq-is-mutable-wait-what/) talking about it.)

In my codebase, I try to follow functional programming best practices and while I did assume `Seq` to enforce an immutable Sequence, it may not be and hence causing an entry-point for unintended side-effects.

In order to protect against mutable Seq I could type my functions using a Sequence with:

`scala.collection.immutable.Seq` in each of my files in which I am expecting a `Seq`.

I also do not prefer to read `immutable.Seq` in my code base.

For me, `Seq` should behave just like `Set` alias and be immutable by default.

Is there a way I can make the default `Seq` alias to point to its immutable counterpart for my project without hindering vendor imports?

Comment: Why do you say `Seq` defaults to mutable? `collection.mutable.Seq` has the `update()` method but `collection.Seq` does not.

Comment: Yeah am I missing something here? I've been using `Seq` for awhile now and have never seen a place where it's mutable. We're talking about the `Seq` returned from `Seq.apply(1, 2, 3)` right?

Comment: @jwvh I rephrased my question.

Comment: @JordanCutler I am talking about what's been pointed out for example here: https://orrsella.com/2014/02/27/the-default-scala-seq-is-mutable-wait-what/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, having read the (4-year old) blog post, I really don't see this as being much of an issue.

The default `Seq()` is `collection.Seq` which isn't mutable itself, but it is the parent of both the mutable and immutable variants. So code that creates and passes default `Seq` collections isn't effected but code that accepts a `Seq` parameter *might* receive a `mutable.Seq`. But that's only an issue if immutability is not just assumed but required, e.g. for thread safety.

Bottom line: Put an `import collection.immutable.Seq` at the top of those files where:

1. Client code *that you don't control* might send you a mutable `Seq`, and
2. The immutability of that received collection is of paramount importance.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend trying to mess with default Scala behaviour. Unless you define your own function which takes any input and returns an immutable Seq of that input, I think it'd be safest to just use `immutable.Seq`

You can always try something like this (not thoroughly tested):

```
def seq(inputs: Any*): scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Any] = {
  scala.collection.immutable.Seq(inputs)
}
```

---

```
scala> seq("hi", true)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Any] = List(WrappedArray(hi, true))

scala> seq(1, 'c', "string", false)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Any] = List(WrappedArray(1, c, string, false))
```

---

**Edit:**

As [jwvh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4993128/jwvh) pointed out, this option isn't ideal. Using generic types like [James Whiteley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8230810/james-whiteley) suggested could be better if you insist on making your own function:

```
def seq[T](inputs: T*): scala.collection.immutable.Seq[T] =
  scala.collection.immutable.Seq(inputs).flatten
```

This outputs:

```
scala> seq("hi", true)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Any] = List(hi, true)
```

But I'll reiterate - it might just be best to use `immutable.Seq` where needed, or find another collection type to use.

Comment: You can also write the function using generic types: `def seq[T](inputs: T*): scala.collection.immutable.Seq[T] = scala.collection.immutable.Seq(inputs).flatten`

Comment: This will give the output as `res0: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Any] = List(hi, true)`, etc.

Comment: This looks like a terrible idea. You loose all type safety and the resulting `seq` has one element, a `WrappedArray`.